# PaxExam and CmPropertyPlaceholder

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, pax-exam

i'm trying to implement PaxExam to test a blueprint camel route:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
   xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
   http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.0.0.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="paxexam.HelloBean">
  <cm:default-properties>
    <cm:property name="greeter" value="Hey"/>
  </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>

<bean id="helloBean" class="me.examples.paxexam.HelloBean">
  <property name="say" value="${greeter} from Camel"/>
</bean>

[...]
```

If the bundle is deployed in Karaf it works, but when i try to run it inside a PaxExam test it fails with a NullPointerException when CmPropertyPlaceholder is initialized :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:394)[:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.compendium.cm.CmPropertyPlaceholder.init(CmPropertyPlaceholder.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_45]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:225)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:838)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:638)[10:org.apache.aries.blueprint:0.3.2]
```

This is my PaxExam Configuration method :

```
@Configuration
public static Option[] configure() throws Exception {
  return new Option[] {
    karafDistributionConfiguration().frameworkUrl(getFrameworkUrl("karaf"))
    .karafVersion("2.2.11")
    .useDeployFolder(false)
    .unpackDirectory(new File("target/exam/unpack")),
    logLevel(LogLevel.INFO),
    keepRuntimeFolder(),
    replaceConfigurationFile("etc/activemq-broker.xml", new File("src/test/resources/activemq-broker-test.xml")),

    features(getKarafStandardFeaturesUrl(), "config", "http"),
    features(getActiveMqFeaturesUrl(), "activemq-blueprint", "activemq-camel"),
    features(getCamelFeaturesUrl(), "camel-core", "camel-blueprint", "camel-jms", 
                    "camel-cxf", "camel-test", "camel-jackson", "camel-quartz"),
    features(getSmixFeaturesUrl(), "saaj", "activemq-broker"),

    streamBundle(bundle().add(Hello.class)
        .add(HelloBean.class)
        .add("OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml",
            new File("src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml").toURL())
        .set(Constants.BUNDLE_SYMBOLICNAME, "me.examples.paxexam")
    .set(Constants.IMPORT_PACKAGE, "org.osgi.service.blueprint,org.slf4j")
        .set(Constants.DYNAMICIMPORT_PACKAGE, "*")
    .build()).start()
  };
}
```

Do i need to do anything special to use cm:property-placeholder with PaxExam?
(Removing the tag make the test run fine)

Thx in advance,
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Karaf Pax-Exam test?
If so you need to make sure you have those properties available that you want to set with the configuration admin service. 
If this is a plain Pax-Exam test you're talking of you need to make sure you have the ConfigurationAdmin Service available. Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/HttpServiceWithConfigAdminIntegrationTest.java) for the later.

Comment: That's exactly what i needed, thanks a lot! It's funny i realize that my code is in fact already based on your project on github and yet You provide me the solution (again)...you are my saviour :)